# How to do this Python subprocess call without using shell=True?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

For example, in /tmp I have files ending in .txt, .doc, and .jpg that I'd like to delete in one step using shred and subprocess.

The following does the job:

```
subprocess.call('bash -c "shred -n 5 -uz /tmp/{*.txt,*.pdf,*.doc}"', shell=True)
```

How would I do this command without using shell=True. I've tried the following:

```
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', '"shred -n 10 -uz /tmp/{*.txt,*.pdf,*.doc}"'])
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', 'shred', '-n 10', '-uz', '/tmp/{*.txt,*.pdf,*.doc}'])
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that other guy is spot on (haven't tried it myself though). However if you ever find yourself having similar issues again [shlex.split(s)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) might be helpful. It takes the string 's' and splits it "using shell-like syntax".

```
In [3]: shlex.split(s)
Out[3]: ['bash', '-c', 'shred -n 5 -uz /tmp/{*.txt,*.pdf,*.doc}']
```

Comment: Wow, that's some good stuff right there. Thanks for informing me.

Comment: You're most welcome. The python standard library is pretty big and there's a lot of useful stuff to discover. If you like a more easily digestible form than the python docs I would suggest [Python Module of the Week](http://pymotw.com/2/contents.html) by Doug Hellman.

Comment: @PythonNoob: note: the very first command in the PyMOTW description of `subprocess` module is incorrect: it uses `shell=True` together with a list argument: do not do that, it is almost always wrong. Read my comments there. Otherwise PyMOTW is a good resource.

Answer (score 1):

```
subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', 'shred -n 10 -uz /tmp/{*.txt,*.pdf,*.doc}'])
```

You can tell how a command is expanded and split up with:

```
$ printf "Argument: %s\n" bash -c "shred -n 5 -uz /tmp/{*.txt,*.pdf,*.doc}"
Argument: bash
Argument: -c
Argument: shred -n 5 -uz /tmp/{*.txt,*.pdf,*.doc}
```

In the more general case (but overkill here), if you're ever in doubt of what's executed by something with which parameters, you can use strace:

```
$ cat script
import subprocess
subprocess.call('bash -c "shred -n 5 -uz /tmp/{*.txt,*.pdf,*.doc}"', shell=True)

$ strace -s 1000 -fe execve python script
...
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "shred -n 5 -uz /tmp/{*.txt,*.pdf,*.doc}"], [/* 49 vars */]) = 0
...
$
```

Answer (score 1):

If the command is coming from a trusted source e.g., it is hardcoded then there is nothing wrong in using `shell=True`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

check_call("shred -n 10 -uz /tmp/{*.txt,*.pdf,*.doc}",
           shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

`/bin/bash` is used to support `{}` inside the command.

This command doesn't run `/bin/sh`